# how to properly use incremental array variable inside str_replace() in PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to create pdf from the values of a dynamic form.

I am collecting and storing dynamic inputs like this.

```
$inputarray = array();
foreach ($_POST['input'] as $input) {
        $inputarray[] = $input;
}
```

Now I want to replace a template with the values collected from the form. My current codes look like this.

```
//count total number of inputs
$icount = count($_POST['input']);

//replace template with values
ob_start();
$require_once 'template.php';
$html = ob_get_clean();
$template = str_replace(array('%name%', '%input0%', '%input1%', '%input2%'), array($name, $inputarray[0], $inputarray[1], $inputarray[2]), $html);
```

The code of my template.php looks like this.

```
<tr><td>%name%</td></tr>
<?php
for ($i=0; $i<$icount; $i++){
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>%input'.$i.'%</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
?>
```

My code is working fine if I use %input1%, %input2% manually. My question is how do I automate that part?

P.S: I am still in beginning stage of learning and not proficient in object-oriented style. If possible, please explain in procedural style.

Edit: I don't understand why my question is closed. I would really like to know from someone that which part of my question is not understandable. English is not my first language and if some parts are not clear enough, at least I deserve specific feedback, not something general like "your question is not clear".

Comment: thanks a lot mod, to reopen my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
$search = array();
$search[] = '%name%';

$replace = array();
$replace[] = $name;

// make sure $_POST['input'] is zero-indexed, otherwise apply `array_values`
foreach ($_POST['input'] as $key => $input) {
    $search[] = '%input' . $key . '%';
    $replace[] = $input;
}
// next
$template = str_replace($search, $replace, $html);
```

Comment: Without messing around with 'template.php', I would just add an `echo $template` at the end in order to output this.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this.

```
$template = '%input2% %input1% %input0% %name%';

$inputarray = [ 'another', "is", "This" ];

foreach ($inputarray as $key => $value) {
    $replacement [ '%input'.$key.'%' ] = $value ;
}

$replacement[ "%name%" ] = 'example';
$template = strtr( $template, $replacement );
```

Comment: that's a concise way to do it, thanks for the suggestion..